# Jackson Prevent Null Deserialization of Enum

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I'm trying to understand how Jackson JSON deserialization understand null values. If I have a JSON that maps a single enum:

```
{
    "myEnum": null
}
```

To a field

```
private myEnum enum;
```

and `myEnum` looks as follows with no null value defined:

```
public enum myEnum {
   foo("foo"),
   bar("bar")
  // ...
}
```

Does Jackson offer a native way to prevent null from being recognized as a valid value for this enum, or does this validation need to be managed in code?

Comment: It all depends. Do you want binding to fail, or do you want to add a validation rule with the validation-api. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Like with all other types of value, Jackson will just put `null`. If you want to validate, you can do it later. You shouldn't do it during deserialization.